# Skyrim "Blood on Ice" Issue

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

This is an issue that I can't seem to find anyone else talking about. So I started "Blood on Ice" a few... hundred... hours ago. However, I didn't sell the strange amulet to Calixto. So I got tired of having it in my inventory and decided to complete it to get rid of it. I completed it in a few minutes (I have done every mission in Skyrim twice, once on 360 and once on PC). However, this time as soon as I completed it, my game keeps repeatedly crashing.

I thought it was mod related, but after disabling them all it still happens. I reloaded an old save and had no problems before completing the quest. But, even with my mods disabled, as soon as I complete the quest I can't save, fast travel, or leave Windhelm without crashing to dashboard. I am running the Unofficial Skyrim Patch and have disabled all mods that have anything to do with modifying graphics, interiors, exteriors, or character models. I thought it might have something to do with the amulets code because of it changing to the Necromancers amulet so I ditched it on the second victim before finishing the quest. Didn't solve it. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the game, and power cycling. I am out of options. I am playing on Xbox One because it has the ability to run it better than my PC. If I had the option I would run it through scrubbers but I can't. Does anyone know what I should do? I don't want to just not complete it because that is giving up. Also, like I said, permanent quest item stuck in inventory. However, I am 177 hours in and can't just restart. I am really hurting here for an answer.

Comment: After reading up about this quest...I convicted the wrong guy.... OOOOOPPPSSS

Comment: Just to clarify: did you reload the old save and complete it again after disabling the mods? Also, what's "CTD"? And "USP".

Comment: USP is Unofficial Skyrim Patch. Not sure about the oyher thing @dcs

Comment: CTD- Crash to Desktop/Dashboard

Comment: @DCShannon CTD is Crash To Desktop, as in the game simply closes instantly.

Comment: When I loaded the old save it was without any of the mods.

Answer (score 2):

This one of those quests that can glitch in so many different ways. So without knowing the exact circumstances and what other quests you have done since starting this one, there could be many things that could have gone wrong. This page

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Blood_on_the_Ice

Has a list of all possible bugs and their workaround if you are on PC.